# Subclipse 400 bad request but works from browser

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I run subversion on a http subdomain hosted by Dreamhost. I have been successfully able to connect to my repository at http://svn.example.me/example through Subclipse before but as of late I get "400 bad request" from both TortoiseSVN and Subclipse.

1. I tried removing my repository and reconnecting but it didn't work
2. I am ABLE to connect over http to http://svn.example.me/example through Google Chrome
3. My developers are able to connect to my repository over http from Mac and Ubuntu machines

Is there a way to find out why I am unable to connect except through a web browser? I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. Again, this worked fine as of until recently. I have tried connecting both from a speedy open network and from my semi-crappy building wifi to no availability.

THANKS for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to go through proxies?  Web browsers only send basic HTTP commands like GET when browsing a repository.  SVN clients send the additional WebDAV HTTP commands like OPTIONS, PROPFIND, etc..  Sometimes proxy servers are configured so that they do not proxy these additional requests.

Using SSL is often an easy way around this since proxies just allow all of the requests to go through.

Comment: I did setup SSL access to my account but I am not sure how to implement that in Eclipse. I tried connecting with svn+ssh://yourDHusername@yourdomain.com/home/yourDHusername/svn/yourrepositoryname/ but I still get a 400 error. This is however likely because I am not sure where to specify my private key to work with Eclipse.

Comment: If you really set up SSL, which was my suggestion, then it would be https://hostname/svn/repos.  The above URL is for SSH which is vastly different.

Comment: You are correct, it was SSH that I set up. I gave up on Subclipse and got my repository connected with TortoiseSVN with Pageant managing the private key. I wasn't able to connect with Subclipse. My SVN Interface client in Eclipse did only have JavaHL available which would apparently require Plink to be setup with the private key.

Comment: If you are using SSH, you probably want to use the SVNKit adapter since that gives you a GUI SSH client.

Comment: I read that the SVNKit adapter has been discontinued/not included in later versions of Subclipse which is why I don't have it. Do you recommend download it separately?